# Grouping Days if hours are same and if days are consecutive add hypenate else comma

Tags: php, days

I have a code where I'm mergin the days with similar opening hours of a store together. For example, if we have:

```
<?php

$openHours = array(
    'Mon' => '9am-7pm',
    'Tue' => '9am-7pm',
    'Wed' => '9am-7pm',
    'Thu' => '9am-6pm',
    'Fri' => 'closed',
    'Sat' => '9am-10pm',
    'Sun' => '9am-10pm'
);


foreach($openHours as $k => $v)
    $array[$v][] = $k;

foreach($array as $time => $days)
    echo implode(",", $days) . " " . $time . PHP_EOL;

?>
```

The result shows like below.

```
Mon,Tue,Wed 9am-7pm
Thu 9am-6pm
Fri closed
Sat,Sun 9am-10pm
```

**What I want?**

I want to hyphenate the if the days are consecutive and add comma if not consecutive example below.

**Result Should be Like this**

```
Mon-Wed 9am-7pm     // Hyphenate as days are consecutive and more than 2
Thu 9am-6pm
Fri closed
Sat,Sun 9am-10pm    // Adds comma as there are only 2
```

Comment: please response on answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

**UPDATE 2**

```
<?php
$openHours = array(
    'Mon' => '9am-7pm',
    'Tue' => '9am-7pm',
    'Wed' => '9am-7pm',
    'Thu' => '9am-10pm',
    'Fri' => 'closed',
    'Sat' => '9am-10pm',
    'Sun' => '9am-10pm'
);
$new_array = array();
foreach($openHours as $key => $value)
{
  if(in_array($value,$new_array))
  {
     $key_new = array_search($value, $new_array);//to get the key of element
     unset($new_array[$key_new]); //remove the element
     $key_new = $key_new.','.$key; //updating the key
     $new_array[$key_new] = $value; //inserting new element to the key 
  }
  else
  {
    $new_array[$key] = $value;
  }
}

foreach ($new_array as $days=>$time){
    $daylist = explode(',',$days);
    if ($time!='closed'){
    if (count($daylist)>2){
        $limit = count($daylist)-1;
        $first = $daylist[0];
        $last = $daylist[$limit];
        //loop will go here.
        if (date('D', strtotime('+'.$limit.' days', strtotime($first)))==$last){
            echo $first.'-'.$last.' '.$time.'<br>';
        } else {
            $sep = '';
            foreach ($daylist as $sepdays){
                echo $sep.$sepdays;
                $sep = ',';
            }
            echo ' '.$time.'<br>';
        }

    } else {
        echo $days.' '.$time.'<br>';
    }
    } else {
        $daylist = explode(',',$days);
        foreach ($daylist as $sepdays){
                echo $sepdays.' '.$time.'<br>';
            }
    }

}
?>
```

**RESULT**

```
Mon-Wed 9am-7pm
Fri closed
Thu,Sat,Sun 9am-10pm
```

Comment: You code is comprehensive, but I have a problem grouping with different days like when I put Tue and Fri as a closed day it shows Tue,Fri instead i need it to be separated.

Comment: Your code seems to work but there seems to be a problem with 2nd grouping it has to add comma as Friday is closed while grouping the second so it has to show like `Mon,Wed 9am-7pm
    Tue 9am-11pm
    Thu,Sat,Sun 9am-10pm
    Fri closed` [PHPSandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/0d8e4a2737e8bf5dedd4de2e1d5c3d53b06ec3f8)

Comment: I'm sorry but I didn't get you. Can you re-explain it please? :)

Comment: The closed option was tested and working fine but it breaks the grouping again see the result - [PHPSandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/5c9eda59609751c428d5998e8cd5dbfb35eb0fe4)

Comment: Yes let me see it @Maqk

Comment: @Maqk, Please see the UPDATED 2 answer.

Comment: That seems to be working after crosschecking :) BTW Thanks bro.

Comment: @Maqk, Always happy to help. :)

Comment: Sorry about the delay. I went home last night. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use like that:

```
$openHours = array(
    'Mon' => '9am-7pm',
    'Tue' => '9am-7pm',
    'Wed' => '9am-7pm',
    'Thu' => '9am-6pm',
    'Fri' => 'closed',
    'Sat' => '9am-10pm',
    'Sun' => '9am-10pm'
);


foreach($openHours as $k => $v){
    $array[$v][] = $k;
}

foreach($array as $time => $days){
  if(count($days) > 2){ // if count more than two days
    echo current($days)."-".end($days) . " " . $time . PHP_EOL."<br/>";
  }
  else{ // if normal like one or two days
    echo implode(",", $days) . " " . $time . PHP_EOL."<br/>";
  }
}
```

**Result:**

```
Mon-Wed 9am-7pm
Thu 9am-6pm
Fri closed
Sat,Sun 9am-10pm
```

**Side Note:**

If you want to use `Sat,Sun` as `Sat-Sun` than just the condition as `if(count($days) > 1){`.

---

**UPDATE 1:**

Example, if `Fri` and `Tue` is closed than this will work.

```
<?php 
$openHours = array(
    'Mon' => '9am-7pm',
    'Tue' => 'closed',
    'Wed' => '9am-7pm',
    'Thu' => '9am-6pm',
    'Fri' => 'closed',
    'Sat' => '9am-10pm',
    'Sun' => '9am-10pm'
);


foreach($openHours as $k => $v){
    $array[$v][] = $k;
}

foreach($array as $time => $days){
  if(count($days) > 2 && $time != 'closed'){ // if count more than two days
    echo current($days)."-".end($days) . " " . $time . PHP_EOL."<br/>";
  }
  elseif($time == 'closed'){ // if count more than two days
    echo implode(" closed<br/>", $days) . " " . $time . PHP_EOL."<br/>";
  }
  else{ // if normal like one or two days
    echo implode(",", $days) . " " . $time . PHP_EOL."<br/>";
  }
}
?>
```

**Result:**

```
Mon,Wed 9am-7pm
Tue closed
Fri closed
Thu 9am-6pm
Sat,Sun 9am-10pm
```

Comment: That looks ok but I have a problem with grouping the closed days. when I put Tue and Fri as a closed day

Comment: @Maqk: if Tue and Fri close, it will display: `Tue,Fri closed`

Comment: Can we not have it separated as those days are not consecutive

Comment: @Maqk: let me check .

Comment: But now it throws another error you can check with another grouping of hours. [PHPSandBox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/166946775e4dae03e15fa07d0e5b2f356d0f4751)

Comment: can u give me example @Maqk

Comment: @Maqk: sorry, it was a issue, adding this `elseif($time == 'closed'){`, please check UPDATE 1

Comment: The closed issue resolved but grouping again messes. If you see this code you will understand how the comma grouping misses now. [PHPSandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/96b0b38e8d28011766272acfb0a5b75f6863147f). Correct results should be like this `Mon-Wed 9am-7pm Thu,Sat,Sun 9am-10pm Fri closed
`